# impossible to install googlemaps/react-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-wrapper

I try to add a map to my app, but just with this command i got an error :

npm install @googlemaps/react-wrapper

the error :

```
168 timing command:install Completed in 85143ms 169 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined 169 verbose stack at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5) 169 verbose stack at validateString (node:internal/validators:120:11) 169 verbose stack at relative (node:path:497:5) 169 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:1072:21 169 verbose stack at Array.map (<anonymous>) 169 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:1070:66 169 verbose stack at Array.map (<anonymous>) 169 verbose stack at Arborist.[rollbackMoveBackRetiredUnchanged] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:1070:8) 169 verbose stack at Arborist.[reifyPackages] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:234:31) 169 verbose stack at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:154:5) 170 verbose cwd C:\sandbox\lotogest 171 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042 172 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@googlemaps/react-wrapper" 173 verbose node v16.14.2 174 verbose npm v8.5.0 175 error code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE 176 error The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined 177 verbose exit 1 178 timing npm Completed in 86178ms 179 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1653832302473 180 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:audit 1653832377685 181 verbose unfinished npm timer auditReport:init 1653832381360 182 verbose unfinished npm timer metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:@firebase/util:1067925 1653832381366 183 verbose unfinished npm timer metavuln:packument:@firebase/util 1653832381366 184 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:unretire 1653832387608 185 verbose code 1 186 error A complete log of this run can be found in: 186 error C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-29T13_51_41_458Z-debug-0.log
```

please help me found the problem and fix it , thanks by advance

Comment: try to delete your node_modules folder and the package-lock.json and "npm i" again.

Comment: Try to install  @googlemaps/react-wrapper as project local package, rather than global package. npm install -S @googlemaps/react-wrapper

Comment: thank you effectively just delete and re-install work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete "node-modules" forlder and re-install "npm i" work like @igor Gonak purpose.